# timeout when running report in Acumatica ERP system

Tags: acumatica, report-designer

I have a problem when I'm running customized report, 
I used this query View to generate the report: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Aenr4I_Yz9RWRSN0RtaXhoSG8

[image]

After Executing finished, report doesn't work and show the timeout error.

[image]

and then I tried to trace this query in the system, and get this query:

```
    SELECT vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BatchNbr], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[RefNbr], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[InvoiceNbr], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[JobOrderNbr], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Customer_Vendor_ID], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceCredit], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceDebit], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseCredit], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseDebit], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Module], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[TranDate], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[TranType], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Customer_Vendor_CD], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Customer_Vendor_Name], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[TranDesc], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Curyid], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[CuryRate], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[FinPeriodID], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountCD], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountDesc], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseBegBalSummary], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseEndBalSummary], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceBegBalSummary], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceEndBalSummary], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseBegBalIDR], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseEndBalIDR], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceBegBalIDR], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceEndBalIDR], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseBegBalJPY], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseEndBalJPY], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceBegBalJPY], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceEndBalJPY], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseBegBalUSD], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BaseEndBalUSD], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceBegBalUSD], vTranPeriodMultiCury.[SourceEndBalUSD], Account.[AccountCD], Account.[Type], Account.[NoteID], NULL, NULL, NULL, Batch.[Module], Batch.[BatchNbr], Batch.[CuryInfoID], Batch.[NoteID], NULL, NULL, NULL FROM vTranPeriodMultiCury vTranPeriodMultiCury LEFT JOIN Account Account ON (Account.CompanyID = 2) AND [Account].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND (vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountID] = Account.[AccountID]) LEFT JOIN Batch Batch ON (Batch.CompanyID = 2) AND [Batch].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND (vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BatchNbr] = Batch.[BatchNbr]) WHERE (vTranPeriodMultiCury.CompanyID = 2) AND (vTranPeriodMultiCury.BranchID IS NULL OR vTranPeriodMultiCury.BranchID IN (1, 2, 3)) AND (((vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountCD] >= NULL OR NULL IS NULL ) AND (vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountCD] <= NULL OR NULL IS NULL ) AND (vTranPeriodMultiCury.[FinPeriodID] = '052017' OR '052017' IS NULL ))) ORDER BY vTranPeriodMultiCury.[AccountCD]  ASC, vTranPeriodMultiCury.[Curyid]  ASC, vTranPeriodMultiCury.[FinPeriodID]  ASC, vTranPeriodMultiCury.[TranDate]  ASC, vTranPeriodMultiCury.[BatchNbr]  ASC OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

My question is in which part of web.config should be possible to change the timeout of executing sql query of report designer ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should increase this `executionTimeOut` in `Location->system.web->httpRuntime` in `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

Also try to execute the Following SQL Query on your SQL Server for your Acumatica ERP's database:

```
use YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
go
exec sp_configure 'remote query timeout (s)',6000
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, I have changed Http executionTimeout = "3600" but still doesn't work. Even though the process not until an hour but the system already shows the error message.

Comment: What are you doing in your report? Have you tried to run SQL Query for Tables' Joins directly on SQL Server?Is it working properly?

Comment: it works if I run SQL for tables Joins directly, but it didn't work if I run the report in the system

Comment: @HariEko try the SQL Query I have added

Comment: sorry, what is this query for ?

Comment: @HariEko it's changing the timeout for remote queries for the SQL Server from default 600 to 6000

Comment: hmm, understood... so it will be changed into 6000 seconds, is it rights ?

Comment: @HariEko yes, exactly

Comment: I already tried your suggestions, I used this query --> exec sp_Configure 'remote query timeout (s)',3600
reconfigure with override , but it still doesn't work

Comment: @HariEko please add the Tables' Joins to the question